# Data Transfer from Nested JSON to TempView in Spark with Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

i am trying to read JSON file from Dataframe.

```
My Code:

package Stream
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

object SparkRestApi {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("blah")
      .config("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
      .master("local[*]")
      //.enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val StreamDF = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json("D:/myfolder/DataStream.json")


    val SOLA= StreamDF.select(col("association_score.overall").as("association_score"),
      col("disease.activity").as("activity"),
      col("disease.id").as("Disease_id"),
      col("Disease.element").as("Disease_element"),
      col("target.name").as("target_name")).show()
```

**Error
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`association_score`'
given input columns: [took, data, query, from, next, data_version, total, size];;**

Very Much Appreciate if anyone suggest how to bring data to **Dataframe or createOrReplaceTempView from JSON file**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DataQuest5 if you observe the schema, association_score is placed as following

data -> association_score

so you'll have to correct your col name to data.association_score.overall from association_score.overall
code:

```
val SOLA= StreamDF.select(col("data.association_score.overall").as("association_score"),
.
.
.
).show()
```

Note: Same goes with other fields too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rohit. Please help me for target.id, Disease.id also do i need to prefix data.

Comment: I don't see schema anymore, could you please add the schema in the question?